# Angular 6 redirecting back to home after navigation

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue in my Angular 6 app where I perform a successful navigation to another view, but then it's automatically redirecting me back to the index view.  I successfully see the contents of the component on screen, `ngOnInit` fires, and I can also get the route params out of the `ActivatedRoute`.

If I enter the URL manually in the address bar, it doesn't navigate back to home.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  Cheers in advance.

**Update 1**

If I use an `a` rather than a `button`, it doesn't redirect.

```
<!-- this will cause the route to redirect back -->
<button 
  class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right"
  [routerLink]="['/destination', _destination.placeId]">
  Edit...
</button>

<!-- This works! -->
<a 
  class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" 
  [routerLink]="['/destination', _destination.placeId]">
  Edit (LINK)
</a>
```

**app.module.ts - routes**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'destination/:id', component: EditDestinationComponent }
], { enableTracing: true })
```

**navigation trigger**

```
<button 
  class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right"
  [routerLink]="['/destination', _destination.placeId]">
  Edit...
</button>
```

**edit-destination.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-destination',
  templateUrl: './edit-destination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-destination.component.css']
})
export class EditDestinationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('loaded edit-destination');
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        tap((params: ParamMap) => console.log(`destination: ${params.get('id')}`))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

}
```

**edit-destination.component.html**

```
<p>
  edit-destination works!
</p>
```

**Router tracing**
[image: snippet of router tracing in browser console]

Comment: Your navigationTrigger value is imperative which means it was triggered by router.navigateByUrl or router.navigate. Also there is id: 1 param. I don't see anything related in the code you show

Comment: @OlenaHoral Yeah I noticed that in the trace logs, thought it was odd, I haven't got any code to do a navigation to that route with an id of 1.

Comment: Do you perhaps use a HttpInterceptor in which you programmatically redirect? Because something awfully similar had happened to an other user here recently.

Comment: @ak.leimrey Nope! At least, none that I've set up myself.

Comment: @ak.leimrey If I use an `a` rather than a `button`, then the redirect issue doesn't happen.

Comment: I just realized... did you just omit this, or didn't you actually bind an action to the button?

Comment: I had no `(click)` binding on the button, just the `[routerLink]`.  I've just removed the `[routerLink]` on the button, added a click binding and used `router.navigateByUrl` but that still causes a redirect.

Comment: I just realized... why by navigateByUrl? why not simply router.navigate([/somepage])
The difference is, it navigates without updating the url, which might be the solution

Comment: No reason, just the first 'navigate' item in the intelisense list that I attempted.  `navigate` has the same issue, though.

Comment: Does this issue appear in every case? Or only one specific component? But altogether, the usage of the router seems so awfully confusing, that I'm not clearly aware what you are attempting to do in the first place. I would suggest you to delete all router implementations and rewrite them.

Comment: Literally all I'm trying to do is navigate to another view.  This is my only other route, the first time I've attempted it.  I have two routes... what's confusing about them?

Comment: I phrased this wrongly, but I would write it differently. I would bind it to a (click) action. I wouldn't add the parameter in the app.modules. You should send add the queryparameter and listen to the target-page of what the incoming url parameter is. I was searching for an appropriate example like this one: https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Comment: @Tom Are you able find solution this problem

Comment: @nik I can't remember what I did now, sorry!

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was using a form tag in the markup, so I figured it was triggering a "form post" when the user clicked the button. Adding **return false;** at the last line of code of the **click** event solved the problem.